# Flask not updating

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a simple program that I got off GeeksForGeeks:

```
# an object of WSGI application
from flask import Flask 
app = Flask(__name__) # Flask constructor

# A decorator used to tell the application
# which URL is associated function
@app.route('/hello')    
def hello():
    return 'HELLO'

if __name__=='__main__':
app.run()
```

But as I attempt to run the following program it does not update and returns a 404 error on google chrome

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "Hey Person!"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I looked the problem up and it seems I have to put `app.run(debug = True)` for it to work. I try this and this is the result:

```
 * Serving Flask app 'Flask testing' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
[31m   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.[0m
[2m   Use a production WSGI server instead.[0m
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
```

And I have to close shell entirely to close it and the URL has still not updated. I don't know what to do at this point.

[image]

Comment: What do you type on chrome to visit the page. It should be `127.0.0.1:5000/hello`

Answer (score 1):

if you could read back what kind of error it gives back on Chrome, that would be helpful.

But based on my limited experience of with flask, I'm guessing it is because you're in the wrong directory.

Flask will port you small webapp onto a address like this
http://127.0.0.1:5000/

but since you have your function routed to

```
@app.route('/hello')
```

You will need to have

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello
```

as the address for this app to work. The numbers before the "/hello" might be different, but you just take what flask ports it to and tag on that line. Hopefully, that helps

Comment: After you change the message that you mean for it to return, did you save first then refresh the page?

Comment: Yes I did multiple times